# Removing array values without losing quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json, unset

My Array :

```
$val=array('a','b','c');
echo json_encode($val);
```

Output : `["a","b","c"]`

Using unset to remove 'b' from location *'1'* : `unset($val[1]);`

Output:`{"0":"a","2":"c"}`

Expecting Output as : `["a","c"]`

Is there any solution ? to get rid of keys and curl brackets and get output as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset array keys. Check this:

```
<?php

$val=array('a','b','c');
echo json_encode($val);

unset($val[1]);

echo json_encode($val); //outputs {"0":"a","2":"c"}


$val = array_values($val); //reset array keys
echo json_encode($val); //outputs ["a","c"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Script Worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) `array_splice($val, 1, 1);` instead of `unset($val[1]);`

```
$val=array('a','b','c');
array_splice($val, 1, 1);
echo json_encode($val);
```

[Test Here](https://ideone.com/gizVgv).